# Need to write a function and assign a new column to the data frame have mulitple values in one column and unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, apply

[image]

How to find the distance for all the points having different groups? So far I tried with column B_id has value=123 with class 1 which will iterate with other columns such as score and re-score in the same group to find the distance

Note: with single B_id we have multiple A_id's

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
def edit_distance(s1, s2):
   return euclidean(s1,s2)

df_ref = df.iloc[1] # Only Class which is flag =1 and same for other groups 


df_distances = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df_distances.append(edit_distance(df_ref.values,row.values))
print(df_distances)
output- [4.3, 0, 3.2, 2.3] #example not exact values
```

The Expected output should be like [image]

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: For the B_id with 123 the expected output - [4.3, 0, 3.4, 2.4] and same with B_id with 1234 will get some output. Note that in 123 group I can take only row with class =1 and multiply with other columns have numerical values with 
Class =0 values to get the distance and follows the same for 1234 group as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community. I hope you want to find the `euclidean distance` for each `B_id` columns between class 1 and class 0. **Here I am assuming that you have a single row for each unique pair of class 1 and B_id**. Then the solution becomes easy. Here is what you can do

```
def ed(rows):
    cls_1 = rows[rows.Class == 1].head(1) # Assuming only single row of class 1 for each B_id
    return rows.apply(lambda x: euclidean(x[['score', 're_score']], 
                                          cls_1[['score', 're_score']]), axis=1)
```

And then you call the function on `groupby` for that column

```
df['distance'] = df.groupby('B_id').apply(ed).values
```

Hope this solves your question.